# How to plot a scatter plot and a line plot on the same graph using Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I've recently gotten into **plotly** and am absolutely loving it, so am trying to use it in each project I do.

With **matplotlib** I can plot a line plot and a scatter plot on the same graph using the code below.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,5))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color = "r")
plt.show()
```

Using the `trendline` parameter in the `scatter` function inside `plotly.express` I can plot a line of *best fit* through the scattered points, but I don't want that as I am trying to demonstrate how to calculate that line.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using same defined arrays / lists, `x, y, y_pred`.  An equivalent approach is to use **Plotly Express** to create a figure then add additional traces to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 16)
y = np.random.uniform(1, 6, 16)
y_pred = y * 1.1

fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, color_discrete_sequence=["yellow"])
fig.add_traces(px.line(x=x, y=y_pred, color_discrete_sequence=["red"]).data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! Just one more quick question. Like we can change the color of the plotted graph in `matplotlib` using the `color` attribute, is there any way to change the graph's color in **plotly**?.

Comment: that's done in code sample with `update_traces(line_color="red")`

Comment: I meant that can we change the color of the plot plotted using `px.scatter(x=x, y=y)`? 

I passed `line_color = "red"` inside the `scatter` function and it threw an error.

Comment: updated answer if you want to do directly within **Plotly Express** call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fig.add_shape` after you have created the scatter plot like so:

```
fig.add_shape(
    type="line",
    x0=0,
    y0=0,
    x1=10,
    y1=10,
    line=dict(width=1, dash="dash"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a line plot instead, you can actually use the `markers` arument:

`px.line(x=x, y=y, markers=True)`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJaaM.png

https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html